# How to show the uniform convergence of $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{e^{n\cos(x)}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $$u_n(x)=\frac{1}{e^{n \cos(x)}} $$ and $$  \sum_{n \geq 1} u_n(x) $$

I proved that this sequence converges whenever $x \in [2k \pi, 2k\pi + \frac{2}{\pi})$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now I am asked to prove its uniform convergence(or disprove it). And that's where I am stuck. I know that the sum equals to $S = \frac{1}{1-e^{\cos(x)}}$, and that the basic way to show uniform convergence is to show that the rest of $\left (S - \sum_{k=0}^{n}u_k(x) \right )$ tends to $0$ when $n$ tends to infinity. Or in other words to show that $\left (\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} u_n(x) \right) \underset{n \infty}{\rightarrow} 0$.

Here, $$ \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} u_n(x) = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^{n(\cos(x))}} \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^n} $$

So is this enough to show that it converges uniformly (if it converges uniformly at all)?

Comment: In your last calculations' line you should have $\;e^k\;$ in the denominator, *not* $\;e^n\;$ .

Comment: the last line is not correct: $e^{ncos(x)}\leq e^{n}$. Moreover, since $\sum_{n\geq 1}u_{n}(2\pi k)=+\infty$, I think this series does not converges uniformly.

Comment: I think Basti has a point there. My answer below refers to what you wrote you showed and yes: that'd be enough to deduce unif. convergence. Yet you must check carefully the inequalities you use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_n$ converges pointwise on $(2\pi k-\pi/2,2\pi k+\pi/2)$ for every $k\in \mathbb Z.$

You've made a mistake on the uniform convergence. Let's look at $(-\pi/2,\pi/2).$ The convergence will be uniform on $[-a,a]$ for every $a\in (0,\pi/2).$ (Use Weierstrass M to show this.) But the convergence is not uniform on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2).$ If it were, then $u_n$ would converge uniformly to $0$ on this interval. But note

$$u_n(\pi/2-1/n) = \frac{1}{e^{n\cos(\pi/2-1/n)}}= \frac{1}{e^{n\sin(1/n)}} \to \frac{1}{e},$$

hence $u_n$ can't converge uniformly to $0.$ (By periodicity this argument is the same in every $(2\pi k-\pi/2,2\pi k+\pi/2).$)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you did is enough as

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{e^k}=0\;,
\;\;\;\text{since}\;\;\;\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{e^k}\;\;\text{converges}$$